# Showing items with variable height in a ListLayout

Tags: listview, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a WinJs metro app containing a `ListView` with items of variable height. It is basically done the same way as in Scenario 4 in the ["HTML ListView item templates" sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-item-templates-7d74826f). A `groupInfo` function is used to enable cell spaning of the `GridLayout` associated with the ListView:

[image: items in grid layout]

Now in my application's snap view I'd like the items to scroll vertically, so I tried to replace the `GridLayout` with a `ListLayout`. This causes vertical scrolling, but now the cell spaning is missing and items overlap:

[image: items in list layout]

I used the `groupInfo` function the same way as with the `GridLayout`, but it seems to be ignored:

```
layout: { 
    groupInfo: groupInfo, 
    type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout 
}
```

Is there a way to use items of variable size in a `ListLayout`? Some of my items have more content than others and I'd really like to use tiles of different sizes to show everything optimally.

Answer (score 0):

> old post
>
> Yes you certainly can customize everything. I think your render
>   problem come from this you may have forget, the `forceLayout`.
>
> ```
> ready: function (element, options) { 
>             element.querySelector("#listView").winControl.forceLayout(); 
>         }
> ```
>
> I don't have my Windows 8 near from me so if no one else reply and the
>   problem didn't come from the `forceLayout` I'll update the response by
>   the night.
>
> I hope this help.

Ok so I've misunderstood your problem earlier.

Here is something which should satisfy you.

The thing is you have to manage the different view state of your application in both JavaScript and CSS files.

So regarding the JavaScript I've used two functions that can be found in Grid Application template for example. So I've modify the scenario4.js to obtain this code.

```
function MyCellSpanningJSTemplate(itemPromise) {
    return itemPromise.then(function (currentItem) {
        var result = document.createElement("div");

        // Use source data to decide what size to make the
        // ListView item
        result.className = currentItem.data.type;
        result.style.overflow = "hidden";

        // Display image
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.className = "regularListIconTextItem-Image";
        image.src = currentItem.data.picture;
        result.appendChild(image);

        var body = document.createElement("div");
        body.className = "regularListIconTextItem-Detail";
        body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        result.appendChild(body);

        // Display title
        var title = document.createElement("h4");
        title.innerText = currentItem.data.title;
        body.appendChild(title);

        // Display text
        var fulltext = document.createElement("h6");
        fulltext.innerText = currentItem.data.text;
        body.appendChild(fulltext);

        return result;
    });
}

var appViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState;
var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView;
var ui = WinJS.UI;

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/scenario4.html", {
        initializeLayout: function (listView, viewState) {
            /// <param name="listView" value="WinJS.UI.ListView.prototype" />

            if (viewState === appViewState.snapped) {
                listView.layout = new ui.ListLayout();
            } 
            else {
                listView.layout = new ui.GridLayout({ groupInfo: groupInfo });
            }
        },
        ready: function (element, options) {
            var listView = element.querySelector("#listView").winControl;
            this.initializeLayout(listView, appView.value);
        },
        updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {

            var listView = element.querySelector("#listView").winControl;

            if (lastViewState !== viewState) {
                if (lastViewState === appViewState.snapped || viewState === appViewState.snapped) {                   
                    this.initializeLayout(listView, viewState);
                } 
                else {
                    listView.layout = new ui.GridLayout({ groupInfo: groupInfo });
                }
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Then I've deleted the entire `layout` property of the listview in the scenario4.html since I create the layout above in the scenario4.js

Therefore your listview uses a different layout depending on the view state but you'll have the same result as you get before (Btw you have to change the scenario while you're in snapped mode to see the result).

So we just have to update the scenario4.css depending on the view state and in CSS 3 we have media queries which are allowing us to do that.
Then depending on the view state here `snapped` we will override our properties. You just have to add the code below to your scenario4.css

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) {
    #listView {
        max-width: 260px;
        height: 280px;
        border: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    }

    .regularListIconTextItem {
        max-width: 250px;
        max-height: 70px;
        padding: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: -ms-grid;
    }

    .smallListIconTextItem {
        max-width: 250px;
        max-height: 70px;
        padding: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: Pink;
        display: -ms-grid;
    }

    /* Medium size */
    .mediumListIconTextItem {
        max-width: 250px;
        max-height: 70px;
        padding: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: LightGreen;
        display: -ms-grid;
    }

    /* Large size */
    .largeListIconTextItem {
        max-width: 250px;
        max-height: 70px;
        padding: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: LightBlue;
        display: -ms-grid;
    }
}
```

Hope this time it helps ;)

Comment: There was already a `forceLayout()` call on `ready`, which didn't help. To test this further I added a button to manually call `forceLayout()`. When you click it you can see that the `ListView` renders itself, but the result still is the same, with overlapping items...

Comment: Ok so I'll be at home in 4 hours I'll try to reproduce your problem and I'll post if I can fix it. Btw you're on the Release Preview or on the Consumer Preview ?

Comment: I'm using the Release Preview.

Comment: Switching the layout and CSS like this should work nicely, I just really would prefer if some items could be larger than others in the snap view/ListLayout. If I make all the items the same size then I don't have enough space in all cases for the data I want to display.

Comment: Yes you certainly could but I'm not sure that you look really nice because the snapped view is pretty tight. Moreover you wouldn't follow the UX guidelines provided by MS for Windows 8 Metro and so your application could be rejected by the store

Comment: @Aymeric The thing is *to have* variable heights in a listlayout... This answer could not be validated because it describes how to have a listlayout with specific unique height.

Answer (score 0):

My general thought is to switch out the template in snapped view to avoid using the MyCellSpanningJSTemplate which does the item template resizing. You can give this try.

1) Create a second item template:

```
    <div id="listLayoutItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
        <div class="regularListIconItem">
            <img src="#" class="regularListIconItem-Image" data-win-bind="src: picture" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

2) detect for snapped view by listening to the resize event (see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Snap-Sample-2dc21ee3)

3) Programmatically change the template to the template in created in step 1.

```
var listView = document.querySelector("#listView").winControl;
listView.itemTemplate = listLayoutItemTemplate;
```

Comment: Actually I do want to have different sizes for my items (some items have more content that needs to be displayed). If I make them all the same size, there is either lots of empty space for many items, or missing important content for some other items...